# Выбрать из MySQL базы строки в которых значение встречается в любом из столбцов

Tags: php, mysql, select

К примеру есть таблица с столбцами i1, i2, i3, i4 и т.д. (около 200 шт).
Нужно сделать выборку по всей таблице, если в любом из столбцов встречается искомое значение?
Вроде: SELECT * FROM table WHERE (i1 OR i2 OR .......) = "44";

Comment: Ну так и делайте, в чем проблема?

Comment: У вас неправильно спроектирована таблица. Если поиск требуется в таком количестве полей, то скорее всего таблица должна быть развернута что бы каждое значение было отдельной строкой. Поиск в такой таблице как у вас возможен только в том виде, как вы написали, с явным перечислением всех полей

Comment: Мысль такая. Есть таблица с товарами и отдельно таблица с запчастями. Одна и та-же деталь встречается в разных товарах в разном количестве с определённым порядковым номером в списке деталей. Я ничего лучше не придумал как завести таблицу со списком деталей к каждому товару. Теперь (как опция) хотелось бы в обратном порядке найти товары в составе которых есть текущая деталь. Буду признателен если кто-нибудь подскажет более "элегантное" решение.

Comment: С синтаксисом почти угадал, правильный -> SELECT * FROM table WHERE "44" in (i1,i2,i3,i4, ........)

Comment: Остаётся открытым вопрос более "правильной" структуры...

Comment: Оставвшийся вопрос выходит за пределы заданного. Создайте новый вопрос.